# Trouble using xpath to get stuff out of XML with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I think I set up the namespace resolver right,

```
var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, //xpathExpression
                               xml,  //contextNode
                               NSResolver, //namespaceResolver
                               XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, //resultType
                               null //result
                              );
```

and I think I am setting path correctly, (Ive tried alot of variation here, pretty much anything that might work)

```
path="/";
```

but the nodes.iterateNext() seems to be telling me I did something wrong :

```
firebug output : nodes : [object XPathResult] length : undefined
```

the x and xml object are good though, because I can see them and the xml in firebug. If you use my code, Im just testing in chrome so if youre using IE you may have a whole other can of worms. :)

Heres the xml (sanitized version)

```
<dataset xmlns="http://stub.test.data1" xmlns:xs="http://another.stub.test.moredata">
<!--
<dataset
    xmlns="http://stub.test.data1"
    xmlns:xs="http://another.stub.test.moredata"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://yet.more.stub.test.data/xmldata.xsd"
>
-->
    <metadata>
        <item name="a" type="xs:string" length="92"/>
        <item name="b" type="xs:string" length="50"/>
        <item name="c" type="xs:short" precision="1"/>
        <item name="d" type="xs:string" length="66"/>
        <item name="e" type="xs:string" length="26"/>
        <item name="f" type="xs:string" length="6"/>
        <item name="g" type="xs:string" length="264"/>
        <item name="h" type="xs:double" precision="2"/>
        <item name="i" type="xs:string" length="22"/>
        <item name="j" type="xs:date"/>
        <item name="k" type="xs:date"/>
        <item name="l" type="xs:string" length="16"/>
        <item name="m" type="xs:short" precision="1"/>
        <item name="n" type="xs:short" precision="1"/>
        <item name="o" type="xs:string" length="50"/>
    </metadata>
    <data>
        <row>
            <value>someData1</value>
            <value>someData2</value>
            <value>someData3</value>
            <value>someData4</value>
            <value>someData5</value>
            <value>someData6</value>
            <value>someData7</value>
            <value>someData8</value>
            <value>someData9</value>
            <value>someData10</value>
            <value>someData11</value>
            <value>someData12</value>
            <value>someData13</value>
            <value>someData14</value>
            <value>someData15</value>
        </row>
    </data>
</dataset>
```

And heres the javascript :

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

    //initializes the request
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);//method, url, optional async defaults to true

    try {xhttp.responseType="msxml-document"} catch(err) {
        console.log('hey, an error occured');
    } // Helping IE

    xhttp.send("");//send the request. Does not return till the response is returned (due to false above)

    return xhttp;
}

function NSResolver(nsPrefix) {
    console.log("nsPrefix : " + nsPrefix);
    if(nsPrefix == "xs") {
        return "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    }
}

function displayNodes() {

    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType=="msxml-document")
    {
        console.log('code for IE');
        console.log('path=' + path);
        xml.setProperty("SelectionLanguage","XPath");
        nodes=xml.selectNodes(path);
        for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
          {
          document.write(nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
          document.write("<br>");
          }
    }

    // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
    {
        console.log('code for chr / ff / op');
        console.log('path=' + path);


        //docs : http://help.dottoro.com/ljruhkuj.php
        var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, //xpathExpression
                               xml,  //contextNode
                               NSResolver, //namespaceResolver
                               XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, //resultType
                               null //result
                              );

        console.log("nodes : " + nodes + " length : " + nodes.length);
        var result=nodes.iterateNext();

        while (result)
          {
              document.write(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
              document.write("<br>");
              result=nodes.iterateNext();
          }
    }

    document.write('shit should have displayed by now');
}


path="/"; 

function reload() {
    x=loadXMLDoc("testxml.xml"); //x is now a XMLHttpRequest object
    xml=x.responseXML; //xml is now a response to the request, or null if it failed

    displayNodes();
    console.log("x (XMLHTTPRequest Object) : " + x);
    console.log("xml (XMLHTTPRequest.responseXML) : " + xml);
}

reload();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Mozilla's documentation for [using XPath in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript), it seems that the XPathResult object has no such property as `length` that you're asking for.

So when firebug says `length : undefined`, that doesn't necessarily mean you've done something wrong in your XPath path or use of `evaluate()`. The only thing you've done wrong that I can see is to ask for `nodes.length`.

If your result were a snapshot, you could ask for nodes.snapshotLength, but it isn't:

> When the result type in the resultType parameter is specified as ANY_TYPE, ... if the returned result type is a node-set then it will only be an UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE.

Now when you iterate, you should get one result node: the document root node, that is, the (invisible) parent of the `<dataset>` element. Next, you're asking it to print `result.childNodes[0].nodeValue`. `result.childNodes[0]` should be the `<dataset>` element. The `.nodeValue` of an element is null, according to [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue). So presumably your document.write() is not showing anything.

Instead, try printing `result.nodeName` ([docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeName)). This should give `#document` for the root node, or else the name of the element you've selected.

And if you're just trying to get *something* working, and verify that it's working, I would change your path to `"/*"`. You'll get a more tangible result, namely, the `<dataset>` element.